# Does anyone know how to write a function in Haskell to calculate octal into hexadecimal-notation?

Tags: haskell, hex, octal

I was supposed to write a code in Haskell which calculates the hexadecimal-notation when I have the octal. Unfortunately, I have no Idea how to start and which functions I have to link. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: So you want to convert something like `"10o"` to `"08h"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read in the octal value (drop the 'o' or other indicator) via [`readOct`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Numeric.html#v:readOct).  Then, take that Integer and convert it to a hex string using [`showHex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Numeric.html#v:showHex), and decorate as you like.

```
main = do
    octStr <- getLine
    let
        val :: Integer
        (val,_):_ = readOct octStr
        hexStr = showHex val ""
    putStrLn hexStr
```

Also, depending on how frequently you do this, you might try and avoid the `String` type and use either `ByteString` (with these [show like functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html#g:11)) or Text (with these [show like functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder-Int.html)).  Seems octal doesn't get much attention, at least not as much as decimal and hexadecimal.

Comment: The basic idea is good, but that code won't work as `readOct` and `showHex` use the `ReadS` and `ShowS` types, they don't go directly from and to `String`s.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Edited; Maybe Fixed.